# GRPC Reusing Without Server Running

Tags: go, grpc-go, protobuf-go

I know there is several projects like grpc-gateway. But these projects generally just proxies the request. So you need to run grpc server on machine as well.

I am trying to find a way run http server that translates http requests into grpc messages and invokes grpc methods without running grpc server. I can map http requests into grpc request messages manually but i think grpc interceptors will not execute in this way.

Is there way to achive these ?

Best regards.

Comment: There is little value in such a solution. gRPC enables remotely invoking methods. Proxying HTTP/JSON requests onto gRPC methods is useful because it provides a way to support both or migrate from HTTP/JSON and gRPC. If you want HTTP/JSON without a gRPC server then you simply invoke the methods directly in response to the HTTP requests.

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin, I want to write code to run both onprem and serverless scenarios with just changing configuration. Now, in onprem version grpc server and grpc-gateway fine. But in serverless version handler will invoked in lambda function and in lambda serving server is not suitable. So, this is the valuable part for me.